# is there any way to make this code works like a prompt when click Download button and asks for password ( provided by me) then Download starts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make this code like - when someone clicks DOWNLOAD Button it asks for a password as a Prompt and opens a download link ( If someone types wrong password it should say "Wrong password try again"
 I am a beginner with this if someone helps me to get this really quick it would be a great help for my site.

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <body>
                    <p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>
                    <button onclick="myFunction()">Download</button>
                    <p id="demo"></p>
                    <script>
                function myFunction() {
                    var person = prompt("Please enter the Password");
                    if(person == '123') {
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You can Download your file now";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Wrong Password";
                    }
                }
                </script>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: it's not secure, because if i use develop mode (f12) i can see if and else.. why don't use php?

Comment: @Rahul - Is your current code not working?

Comment: Simone Rossaini, I am using blogger its difficult for me to implement this php stuff

Comment: @Ramesh No not working, i have problem with integration how to set the password promt when someone clicks download

Comment: @Rahul - It's working fine for me, another than the fact that it's not secure, everything looks okay.

Comment: @Ramesh ok i will try again, is there any way to put redirect link after clicking correct password, download will automatically starts? sorry i am very beginner i have found the codes right but can't implement inside this code at last i suffer some errors

Comment: huh so no correct code : (